# As Fall Planting comes help promote Gardening.SE

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Fall planting season is coming, there will hopefully be lots of gardeners planting fall gardens, and they'll have lots of questions. Essentially, this is a great time to recruit new members!

What can you do to help?

1. As you plant your fall garden, whenever you have on topic questions, no matter how silly, ask them here. You're not the only one having that question. Hundreds of other people will, too. Ask them even if you think you're going to be able to find the answer yourself... and if you do find the answer, go ahead and answer it yourself.
2. When answering fall gardening questions, do everything you can to overkill it. Don't just answer with a hyperlink to some other discussion group somewhere. Write a detailed, step-by-step, ultra-clear guide with pictures and examples. Help us have the best possible answer to the common problems and questions people have with fall gardening.
3. If a question comes in that is unclear, badly written, badly formatted, or in bad English, edit it into shape. We've always encouraged edits that improve spelling, grammar, and clarity. Make every question into a full sentence.

This is a great opportunity to build up a body of answers to common fall gardening questions that will (hopefully) be super-popular in the coming months as the rest of the gardening universe starts planting. Those questions will bring in lots of traffic from search engines and if Gardening.SE continues to have great answers, we stand a chance of attracting some great new users who will add value for years to come.

(Idea and text cribbed nearly entirely from [Joel Spolsky](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/589/now-that-lion-is-out-help-promote-ask-different))

Feel free to offer any other suggestions as to what we can do to further promote the site.

Also to our Aussie friends and those of the rest of you South of the Equator your spring is coming, please follow the same instructions about spring planting (we will probably do a similar push in the new year when the northern hemisphere starts to plant).

Answer (score 8):

+1, good call!

It's a good time for questions not just on "fall planting". Also:

- Harvesting late-season crops.
- Putting the garden to bed for the winter.
- Prepping for next season.
- Cleanup / hygiene of removing crop debris.
- Planting cover crops to protect and build the soil.
- Using season extenders.
- Collecting seed for next season.

Comment: yes, and because this is a new season for us to be online none of those will be duplicates.